# Как правильно повернуть многоугольник по заданным параметрам d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Есть полигон (многоугольник). Нужно его повернуть с заданным параметром `D`,
где `D` принадлежит `(0, 360)`. При этом, ось вращения зависит от нормальной длины объекта и она тоже задана `(X1 , Y1)`.

Вот мой полигон, рисую так:

```
polygon2.attr("transform", "translate(300,150), rotate('90')");
```

Почему ничего не работает в этой строке?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<html> <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("height", 400)
   .attr("width", 400);
var polygon2=canvas.append("polygon")
polygon2=canvas.append("polygon")
   .attr("points", [122,122,133,133,144,155,122,155])
   .style("fill", "green")
   .style("stroke", "black")
   .style("strokeWidth", "1px")
 polygon2.attr("transform", "translate(300,150), rotate('90')");
 //
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение атрибута `transform` имеет синтаксис без запятых и кавычек:

```
polygon2.attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate(90)");
```

```js
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", 400)
  .attr("width", 400);

var polygon2 = canvas.append("polygon")
  .attr("points", [122, 122, 133, 133, 144, 155, 122, 155])
  .style("fill", "green")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("strokeWidth", "1px")


setInterval(() => {
  let rot = Math.sin(Date.now() / 1000) * 180;
  polygon2.attr("transform", ` translate(40,40)rotate(${rot})translate(-122,-122)`);
}, 20)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Stranger in the Q ? А если мне нужно параметрически изменять то как я вставлю парметры, они ведь заштрихованы (бледным цветом)?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts про какие параметры речь, параметры поворота?

Comment: !!! Нужно вставить переменные какие нибудь,но тогда не работает вот что я имею ввиду `polygon2.attr("transform", "translate(x1,y1) rotate(d1)");`Как встроить свои переменные вместо чисел?Благодарю Вас!!!

Comment: @ArthurAlunts через шаоблоны строк, например, я попозже вам отвечу, сейчас нету компа

Comment: браво блеск блеск шик шок